# jQuery - Iterate through data stored object

Tags: jquery

I encounter something quite strange while trying to iterate properties of an object stored 
using jQuery data function.

Here is the thing (as an example) :

```
wrapper.data( 'infos', {
    label: $('input[name*="label"]').val(),
    amount: $('input[name*="amount"]').val(),
    etc..
});
```

Then i try to read values using :

```
$.each( wrapper.data('infos'), function(k,v) {
  console.log(k + ' > ' + v);
});
```

And i get a beautiful output like :

```
0 > undefined
1 > undefined
... 
239 > undefined
```

If i output this object as if, i can read properties without any difficulties.
Is it somehow related to jquery caching or something ?

Comment: can you put the output of console.log(wrapper.data('infos')) in pastebin or jsfiddle ?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? This works as expected (http://jsfiddle.net/27dCJ/) for me (jQuery 1.7.2). I'd also consider including a jsFiddle showing the problem *live*.

Comment: Check this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2kW29/).

Comment: @Matt : I'm using jQuery 1.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your object has a `length` property, it is being interpeted as an array as, in 1.7.2 at least, whether it's an array or not is determined via:

```
length = obj.length,            
isObj = length === undefined || jQuery.isFunction( obj );
```

So you should either;

1. Call your `length` property something else
2. Use a `for / in` loop instead.

   ```
   var data = wrapper.data('infos')

   for (var x in data) {
       if (data.hasOwnProperty(x)) { // omit properties from the prototype chain
           console.log(x + ' > ' + data[x]);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I'd rather use the for/in loop, it works perfectly in my case.
Thanks a lot, you really helped me out !